# Моделирование арифметических и логических операций процессора

Tags: java, emu8086

Подскажите, как можно сделать умножение(MUL) и деление(DIV) используя побитовые операции ? Например сложение(ADD) и вычитание(SUB) можно сделать так:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(add(4, 5));
        System.out.println(sub(4, 5));
    }

    static int add(int a, int b){
        return b == 0 ? a : add(a ^ b, (a & b) << 1);
    }


    static int sub(int a, int b) {
        return b == 0 ? a : sub(a ^ b, (~a & b) << 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Умножение это сложение со сдвигом. Деление это вычитание, пока уменьшаемое меньше вычитаемого. Вообще очень подробно это оасписано в 1 томе Кнута и в книге Адгоритмические трюки для программистов